# Xamarin.IOS UILocalNotification.UserInfo is null after closing application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, notifications

Local notification works as it should when application is opened. But there are cases when local notification remains in notification center after closing application. And then clicking on notification starts application and notification data should be passed in options in *AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching* method. Options contains key *UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey* which has value of type *UIKit.UILocalNotification*. This value contains UserInfo property which should be filled with notification data. But this UserInfo is null.

Another problem is when local notification remains in notification center and application is restarted. Clicking on notification causes application to start again and it stops immediately.

Have you had such problem? Is it problem with Xamarin? How to handle such scenarios?

Creating notification:

```
public void DisplayNotification(MessageInfo info)
{
    var notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.Current;

    var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
    content.Title = info.Title;
    content.Body = info.Body;
    content.UserInfo = IosStaticMethods.CreateNsDictFromMessageInfo(info);

    UNNotificationTrigger trigger;
    trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(0.1, false);
    var id = (++_LastNotificationId).ToString();
    var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(id, content, trigger);

    notificationCenter.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();

    notificationCenter.AddNotificationRequest(request, (error) =>
    {
        //handle error
    });
}

internal class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Handling notification in AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching

```
if (options != null)
{
    var notification = options["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey"] as UIKit.UILocalNotification;
    var userInfo = notification.UserInfo;//the userInfo is null
}
```

Comment: Did you try handling it in app did become active?? Is user info null even in AppDidBecomeActive life cycle event

Comment: I do not see any event or method named AppDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems NSDictionary should not contain NSNull values. After removing NSNull values everything is OK even if NSDictionary documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary says NSNull is allowed.